# What Prototype-only lightboxes are available?

Tags: image, prototype-js

I'm looking for a good lightbox to show images. It would be nice if the lightbox would also be able to show Youtube videos, but this is not necessary.

Unfortunately most good lightboxes and Magento lightbox extensions rely on jQuery. I don't want to add the jQuery library to the template, because this increases the page data size. So I'm looking for Prototype lightboxes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/. It uses scriptaculous and prototype. So there is a bit of an overhead. 
However, I would highly recommend using jquery with Magento and use the google cache for including it in your installation. This way it will not massively increase your page load times.

PS: Another one is http://home.comcast.net/~ahavriluk/lightboxEx/doc/.

Comment: Note, that lightview is not free for any type of use (even non-commercial use requires a small fee).

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google (the first result actually) returns a website that lists the "top 10" prototype compatible lightboxes. Here is the link: http://www.macnative.com/prototype-lightbox-clones-top-10/

As per my comment below, I've used both Lightview and Prototype Window, however I personally consider Prototype Window ugly. It has pre-defind themes none of which are particularly modern so in that instance I just styled my own. Lightview has what I would call the "standard lightbox effect" window so didn't require this additional styling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for one or two? This might help OP with deciding on one.

Comment: Please update your answer, this is great information. thanks for sharing!